# JSON nesting best practice

Tags: json

I need to reformat the JSON below so the data is formatted with a level heirarchy, it currently looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "level": "level 1",
    "name": "HTML5"
  },
  {
    "level": "level 1",
    "name": "CSS3"
  },
  {
    "level": "level 1",
    "name": "SASS/LESS"
  },
  {
    "level": "level 1",
    "name": "Git"
  },
  {
    "level": "level 2",
    "name": "MySQL"
  },
  {
    "level": "level 2",
    "name": "Server Management (using Apache/Nginx)"
  },
  {
    "level": "level 2",
    "name": "CMS Templating (Perch, Wordpress, Symfony, Laravel)"
  },
  {
    "level": "level 2",
    "name": "Illustration"
  },
  {
    "level": "level 3",
    "name": "OOP PHP"
  },
  {
    "level": "level 3",
    "name": "CMS Templating (Drupal, EpiServer, Umbraco)"
  },
  {
    "level": "level 3",
    "name": "3d Modelling"
  }
]
```

but I want it to be more nested so that each skill is grouped by level. I tried the following but I don't think I've written it correctly as I can't see a good way to access the level names.

```
[
    {
        "level": {
            "expert" : [
                { "name" : "HTML5" },
                { "name" : "CSS3" },
                { "name" : "SASS/LESS" },
                { "name" : "Git" }
            ],
            "middle-weight" : [
                { "name" : "MySQL" },
                { "name" : "Server Management (using Apache/Nginx)" },
                { "name" : "CMS Templating (Perch, Wordpress, Symfony, Laravel)" },
                { "name" : "Illustration" }
            ],
            "competent": [
                { "name" : "OOP PHP" },
                { "name" : "CMS Templating (Drupal, EpiServer, Umbraco)" },
                { "name" : "3d Modelling" }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Could someone please suggest the best way to format the JSON so it makes the most sense.

Note: Just to be clear, I'm not asking for help on how to traverse the data, I'm asking for help on the most optimal way to lay it out. This is a very different way of thinking from the table-based data I'm used to working with.

Comment: `data[0].level.expert`? - And then iterate? And what is the question?

Comment: Just iterate over the array and push in the predefined object depending on the `level` attribute

Comment: If you want to manipulate your data dynamically, it's usually better to have only arrays of objects, no matter the depth. For instance, you can have `var level = [{name: 'expert', categories: […]}, {name: 'competent', categories: […]}, …];`. It also allows you to order the level without the need of an additional field, for instance.

Comment: I find your solution not bad, you can use the key to access the level names? or what is your problem when accessing the level name? Just a small design hint: the ``name`` attribute is redundant

Comment: Do you want to use keys/IDs to access the skills? `{ "level1": { "1234": { "name": "HTML" } } }` or where exactly is your problem in accessing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more straight forward way would be to just use the `level1`, `level2`, `level3` as array properties.

```js
{
  "level1": [
    {
      "name": "HTML"
    },
    {
      "name": "CSS3"
    }
  ],
  "level2": [
    { 
      "name" : "MySQL"
    }
  ],
  "level3": [
    {
      "name": "3d Modelling"
    }
  ]
}
```

You may access the names by using `level1[0].name` e.g.

But it **depends on the use case**, if your level objects need more information within them do it like aove, so you can extend them. If you are only needing the strings, you can also simplify it and just use the strings of the skills directly in the array:

```js
{
  "level1": [
    "HTML",
    "CSS3"
  ],
  "level2": [
    "MySQL",
    "Server Management (using Apache/Nginx)"
  ],
  "level3" : []
}
```

And in this case you acces the skills just by using `level1[0]` directly.

Answer (score -1):

1. prepare the new result object

   ```
   var result = {
     level: {
       expert: [],
       competent: []
     }
   };
   ```
2. iterative over the array

   ```
   for (var i = 0, max = array.length; i < max; i += 1) {}
   ```
3. check each object for the value in level

   ```
   switch (array[i].level) {
     case 'level 1': //...
   }
   ```
4. push objects in the according property, dependent on the switch

   ```
   result.level.expert.push({ name: array[i].name })
   ```
5. output as JSON:

   ```
   JSON.stringify(result);
   ```

Comment: It's explicitly stated in the question that the OP is `not asking for help on how to traverse the data` but `asking for help on the most optimal way to lay it out`.

Comment: sorry, this must have been added later